# Connecting to GKE POD running Postgres with client Postico 2

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, postico

I want to connect to a Postgres instance that it is in a pod in GKE.

I think a way to achieve this can be with kubectl port forwarding.

In my local I have "Docker for desktop" and when I apply the yamls files I am able to connect to the database. The yamls I am using in GKE are almost identical

**secrets.yaml**

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
      namespace: staging
      name: postgres-secrets
    type: Opaque
    data:
      MYAPPAPI_DATABASE_NAME: XXXENCODEDXXX
      MYAPPAPI_DATABASE_USERNAME: XXXENCODEDXXX
      MYAPPAPI_DATABASE_PASSWORD: XXXENCODEDXXX
```

**pv.yaml**

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolume
    metadata:
      namespace: staging
      name: db-data-pv
      labels:
        type: local
    spec:
      storageClassName: generic
      capacity: 
        storage: 1Gi
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
      hostPath:
        path: "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

**pvc.yaml**

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      namespace: staging
      name: db-data-pvc
    spec:
      storageClassName: generic
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 500Mi
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
    # Deployment
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      namespace: staging
      labels:
        app: postgres-db
      name: postgres-db
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: postgres-db
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: postgres-db
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: postgres-db
              image: postgres:12.4
              ports:
                - containerPort: 5432
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
                  name: postgres-db
              env:
                - name: POSTGRES_USER
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: postgres-secrets
                      key: MYAPPAPI_DATABASE_USERNAME

                - name: POSTGRES_DB
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: postgres-secrets
                      key: MYAPPAPI_DATABASE_NAME

                - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: postgres-secrets
                      key: MYAPPAPI_DATABASE_PASSWORD
          volumes:
            - name: postgres-db
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: db-data-pvc
```

**svc.yaml**

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      namespace: staging
      labels:
        app: postgres-db
      name: postgresdb-service
    spec:
      type: ClusterIP
      selector:
        app: postgres-db
      ports:
        - port: 5432
```

and it seems that everything is working

Then I execute `kubectl port-forward postgres-db-podname 5433:5432 -n staging` and when I try to connect it throws

`FATAL:  role "myappuserdb" does not exist`

---

UPDATE 1

This is from GKE YAML

```
spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: MYAPPAPI_DATABASE_NAME
              name: postgres-secrets
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: MYAPPAPI_DATABASE_USERNAME
              name: postgres-secrets
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: MYAPPAPI_DATABASE_PASSWORD
              name: postgres-secrets
```

---

UPDATE 2

I will explain what happened and how I solve this.

The first time I applied the files, `kubectl apply -f k8s/`, in the deployment, the environment variable POSTGRES_USER was referencing a wrong secret, MYAPPAPI_DATABASE_NAME and it should make reference to MYAPPAPI_DATABASE_USERNAME.

After this first time, everytime I did `kubectl delete -f k8s/` the resources were deleted. However, when I created the resources again, the data that I created in the previous step was not cleaned.

I deleted the cluster and created a new cluster and everything worked. I need to check if there is a way to clean the data in kubernetes volume.

Comment: is your   `MYAPPAPI_DATABASE_USERNAME` = `myappuserdb` ?

Comment: @H.R.Emon thanks for the comment, yes, but it is encoded in base64 bXlhcHB1c2VyZGI=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your deployment's `env` spec you have assigned the wrong value for `POSTGRES_USER`. you have assigned the value `POSTGRES_USER = MYAPPAPI_DATABASE_NAME`.

but i think it should  be `POSTGRES_USER = MYAPPAPI_DATABASE_USERNAME` .

```
              env:
                - name: POSTGRES_USER
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: postgres-secrets
                      key: MYAPPAPI_DATABASE_NAME #<<<this is the value need to change>>>
```

please try this one

```
              env:
                - name: POSTGRES_USER
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: postgres-secrets
                      key: MYAPPAPI_DATABASE_USERNAME
```

Comment: you are right, that was a mistake. I deleted the and created everything again. But I am doing another thing wrong because I am getting the same error message. Thanks

Comment: can you share your connection string ? i mean how you are trying to connect with your postgres?

Comment: I am trying with `Postico 2`, but now I tried with command line and I get the same error. `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433 -U admmiappdb miappsqldev`

Comment: can you help me with sharing error again? i think the problem is with the `POSTGRES_USER` you are providing. and one more thing can you check the `POSTGRES_USER` value from container with `echo $POSTGRES_USER`?

Comment: thanks for your help. I entered to the container and I was able to check that the environment variables were setup right `echo $POSTGRES_DB => myappsqldev || echo $POSTGRES_USER => admmyappdb || echo $POSTGRES_PASSWORD => admmyapppass`. If i execute  `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433 -U admmyappdb myappsqldev` I get `psql: error: FATAL:  role "admmyappdb" does not exist`.

Comment: Your answer and comments lead me to the problem, I will look for the solution. It is like `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` are not being used, I was able to connect passing the db name ad db name and username. Thanks @H.R. Emon